# Alternative for texture support of CanvasRenderer in Three.js r49?

Tags: three.js

In Three.js r47, I used CanvasRenderer to draw some objects with image texture. Then I upgrade Three.js to r49 and all these objects dont show up anymore. The change log of r49 reads that "Removed Lamber Texture support in CanvasRenderer". So I think this is the reason.

My question is does Three.js support an alternative to draw texture objects by CanvasRenderer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MeshBasicMaterial` instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this for material `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("abc.png"), overdraw: false});`. But it doesnt show up after upgrading.

Comment: Does this example show the texture? http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_earth.html

Comment: Yes...I'll check my apps again. Thanks for the info.